How to read message directly from kafka offset and write into text file using nodjs
I want to update the textfile.
First, I want it to read the message directly from Offest rather than the received message.
After reading the message, it should be updated in the text file.
I'd like to use a for loop from offset 0 to indefinite .
    const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const fs = require('fs');

// Kafka configuration
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: 'localhost:9092' });
const topicName = 'TopicName'; // Kafka topic name
const logFile = 'logFile.txt'; // File to store messages

// Create a writable stream to the log file
const logStream = fs.createWriteStream(logFile, { flags: 'a' });

// Function to write messages to the log file
function writeMessages(messages) {
  messages.forEach((message) => {
    logStream.write(`${message.value}\n`, 'utf-8');
  });
}

// Function to fetch and write messages starting from a given offset
function fetchAndWriteMessages(startOffset, endOffset) {
  const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client, [{ topic: topicName, partition: 0, offset: startOffset }], { autoCommit: false });

  consumer.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message.value);
    writeMessages([message]);
  });

  consumer.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Consumer error:', error);
  });

  consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', (topic) => {
    console.error('Offset out of range:', topic);
  });

  // Increase the maximum number of listeners for the KafkaClient
  client.setMaxListeners(100); // Set the value as needed

  // Fetch and write messages recursively until the end offset is reached
  if (startOffset < endOffset) {
    fetchAndWriteMessages(startOffset + 1, endOffset);
  }
}

// Function to fetch and write messages for all offsets
function fetchAllOffsets() {
  const offset = new kafka.Offset(client);
  offset.fetch([{ topic: topicName, partition: 0, time: -1 }], (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching offsets:', error);
      return;
    }

    const latestOffset = data[topicName][0];
    fetchAndWriteMessages(0, latestOffset);
  });
}

// Start fetching and writing messages for all offsets
fetchAllOffsets();

in this i want to use for loop so that it will start from 0 offset to indefinite until the message is recived from kafka .
